# set status header not working

Tags: php, http-status-code-404, codeigniter-3

set status header shows a blank page.

```
$this->output->set_status_header('404');
```

My complete code in codeigniter 3.1.8 and php 7.1

```
public function oops()
{
    $this->output->set_status_header('404');
    //$this->last_set_status_code = '404';
    //header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
    //$this->load->view('oops');
    redirect(base_url(),'refresh');
}
```

Comment: A redirect sets the status code to a 3xx (like a 302 for temporary redirects), so your redirect will override the 404. You need to decide if you want to show a 404 and stay on the URL _or_ send a redirect. You can't do both.

Comment: i want to send a 404 header to the browser (SEO) so that the URLs wont be crawled again. At the same time, the user will redirect to home page or custom error page.

Comment: You need to decide if you want to either send a 404 _or_ a redirect code. You can't do both like this. You can show a custom error page in your oops()-controller though. Just load that view instead of redirecting.

Comment: Well, I strongly believe we can do both. Setting up header 404 has nothing to do with the view page. I have implemented the same in other projects. This is the first time I'm using codeigniter 3.1.8 so I doubt whether it is related to the new CI update. It works fine with CI 3.1.6 and php 7.1 combo.

Comment: _"Well, I strongly believe we can do both"_ - You're free to believe what you like, but a http response can only have _one_ status code. Here, you're first setting the status code to 404. When you then do a redirect, it _overrides_ that status code to a redirect status code (a 3xx-status code instead). A redirect is basically a status code with a location header. If you want the response to be 404 and redirect the user, you need to redirect the user using javascript or something on the page instead. You can't do both from PHP in the same response.

Comment: Also remember that the override happens _before_ the response and the headers actually are sent to the client.

Comment: great. removed the redirect and uncommented the $this->load->view('oops'); fixed the issue for me. Thanks. ;)

Answer (score 0):

**To show_404 -**

```
 <?php
    class MY_Exceptions extends CI_Exceptions {

        public function show_404()
        {
            $CI =& get_instance();
            $CI->load->view('my_notfound_view');
            echo $CI->output->get_output();
            exit;
        }
  }
```